# For the Data Update

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am begginner in php. I create a simple Dyanamic site. first I fetch all information from database.and Take for the Edit formate all is going correct but I have problem in quantity input. when the i input the next value inside so that before all entries automatic changeed.....how????

Update formate Code....

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">

    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:24px">Name &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="font-size:24px"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td><br />
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:24px">Project Name &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="font-size:24px"><?php echo $data['project_name']; ?> </td> <br />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:24px">cost &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="font-size:24px"><?php echo $data['cost']; ?> </td><br />
    </tr>
    <div>
        <span><label>Payment 1 </label></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $data['payment_1']; ?>" name="payment_1"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span><label>Payment 2</label></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $data['payment_2']; ?>" name="payment_2"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><label>Payment 3</label></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $data['payment_3']; ?>" name="payment_3"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><label>Payment 4</label></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $data['payment_4']; ?>" name="payment_4"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><label>Payment 5</label></span>
        <span><input type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $data['payment_5']; ?>" name="payment_5"></span>
    </div>                          
   <div>
        <span><button type="submit" class="submit_btn" href="">Submit</button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: and Update Query this.....


<?php
include"config.php";

 $payment_1=$_POST['payment_1'];
 $payment_2=$_POST['payment_2'];
  $payment_3=$_POST['payment_3'];
 $payment_4=$_POST['payment_4'];
 $payment_5=$_POST['payment_5'];
   
 
$mysql="UPDATE  client SET payment_1='$payment_1', payment_2='$payment_2', payment_3='$payment_3', payment_4='$payment_4', payment_5='$payment_5'"; 
//echo $mysql;  die();
$result=mysql_query($mysql);
header("location:all_client.php"); 

?>

Comment: Please edit your question to include the above code.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `Where` clause. With out the clause it is updating all the rows.

```
$mysql="UPDATE client SET payment_1='$payment_1', payment_2='$payment_2', payment_3='$payment_3', payment_4='$payment_4', payment_5='$payment_5' where ...";
```

Please do the escaping atleast.

Comment: i m douing this bt is's nt working

<?php
include"config.php";

 $payment_1=$_POST['payment_1'];
 $payment_2=$_POST['payment_2'];
  $payment_3=$_POST['payment_3'];
 $payment_4=$_POST['payment_4'];
 $payment_5=$_POST['payment_5'];
   
 

$mysql="UPDATE client SET payment_1='$payment_1', payment_2='$payment_2', payment_3='$payment_3', payment_4='$payment_4', payment_5='$payment_5' where client";
//echo $mysql;  die();
$result=mysql_query($mysql);
header("location:all_client.php"); 

?>



Client is a table name/...

Comment: There must some id or key by which you vl identify which record to update, right?

Comment: bt in this not perticular data update



in this any type  and all data updates...??

Comment: without where all the records will be updated.. you want that?

Answer (score 0):

@bhupender what is your main error? as you stated in your comment your mysql update code. i didnt see any WHERE Clause.

---Answer---

use mysqli instead of mysql because it's already deprecated.

using UPDATE you should'nt forget the WHERE Clause. then do the escaping strings with prepare statement.

```
$query=$mysqli_prepare($mysql);
$query->execute();
```

or better see this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539927/updating-data-into-mysql-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment. When you get enough reputation you'll be be able to comment on other people's questions.

Comment: im sorry i cant comment it out sorry for this

Comment: I know, that's what I said. Until you get enough reputation, you can't comment. That doesn't mean you should post a fake answer instead.